# Text advancing by a few pixels per character

Tags: css, firefox, fonts, textarea, mozilla

I made a font. Some characters are intended to be combined (one glyph overlaid onto another, similar to प + े = पे).

This works fine when I import the font into a document editor, for instance, Libre Office. It also works fine when I type the script in a textarea in Google Chrome.

However, when the font is used in a textarea in Firefox, a tiny increment is made after each character, even though the horizontal advance is set to 0 in the TTF font file data.

This seems to be something built into Firefox, but it makes the combining look a bit off, and, if I wanted to overlay several characters on each other, it would look very bad. I think I read somewhere that Firefox knows to turn this off for certain fonts, but I cannot figure out how to do it. Or perhaps there's something in the CSS styling for the textarea? I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does CSS `letter-spacing: 0;` make it what it should be, or messing with that negative or positive get you anywhere?

Or check out the property font-kerning as well.

Comment: Ahah! using "letter-spacing: -1px" worked. Not the nicest solution, since it's browser-specific and font-specific and doesn't make a lot of sense, but thank you, it gets it working!

Comment: I wonder if there's some floating-point comparison or rounding error or something causing it to go ahead by one pixel

Comment: No problem. I don't know much about fonts, but I would imagine that depending on default rendering sizes and scaling that one rendering would decide that all pixels at x-value whatever get an alias left, while another would decide an alias right. Just a heads up; check how using a px value works with scaling font size. It may break down and you could actually need to use a fractional em value. I would urge you to try and find the em value that is the exact center of the range that snaps the pixel to where you need it, as that probably has the best chance of multi-browser support. Good Luck!

Comment: Good point! It appears that "-.05em" is the right correction amount (only applied in Firefox, using "@-moz-document url-prefix() {...}")

Comment: With more intensive testing, it seems to range from -.03em to -.05em, depending on the zoom factor. I'm choosing -.04em, since it's close enough to not be noticeable in any real case.

Comment: OKAY, a better solution: Now I'm saving my font off to an OTF (instead of TTF), and the misalignment doesn't seem to occur at all.